# Scala Task return mapping

Tags: java, scala, monix

I have a method readHeader which takes one argument and returns **Task[List[Header]]** and another method calls for multiple ids and returns **List[Task[List[EquipmentHeader]]]**.
How to make a return of **Task[List[List[Header]]]** compatible with multiple id read function.

```
trait M1{
  def readHeader(id: String): Task[List[Header]]
}

def read(ids: List[String])(implicit m1:M1):Task[List[List[Header]]] = {
    if (ids.isEmpty) {
      Task(List.empty)
    } else {
         ids.map(m1.readHeader(_)) //List[Task[List[Header]]]
    }
  }
```

Comment: I believe you should be able to get what you want using `ids.traverse(m1.readHeader)` if you get a not method error you would need to `import cats.implicits._` first.

Comment: Can you explain what cats library does and if not using cats, how it can be done in scala using flat map or any other API

Comment: If you are using **Monix** I am pretty sure you are already using **cats** _(transitively)_ and if not, then there isn't really any reason to do not do it, both libraries work very well together. And while you may implement this using standard methods, it would be somewhat difficult. I would recommend you read [**this**](https://underscore.io/books/scala-with-cats/) book to understand the `Traversable` abstraction _(and many others)_.

Comment: can you explain if not using cats how to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `traverse` from [cats](https://github.com/typelevel/cats):

```
import cats.implicits._

ids.traverse(m1.readHeader) // Task[List[List[Header]]]
```

Comment: This works, can you explain how to do in a flat map without using cats library.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a naive implementation of `traverse` for just **Task** and **List**.
But again, I insist, there is no reason for not using the one defined in *cats*.

```
def traverse[A, B](list: List[A])(f: A => Task[B]): Task[List[B]] = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(remaining: List[A], acc: Task[List[B]]): Task[List[B]] =
    remaining match {
      case a :: as =>
        loop(
          remaining = as,
          acc = for {
            b <- f(a)
            bs <- acc
          } yield b :: bs
        )

      case Nil =>
        acc.map(_.reverse)
    }
  loop(remaining = list, acc = Task.pure(List.empty))
}
```