# Convert List[Task[List[A]]] to Task[List[A]]

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats, monix

How to convert **List[Task[List[Header]]]** type to  **Task[List[Header]]** in scala .

I have a method which returns Task[List[Header]] and calling dor multiple times it becomes List[Task[List[Header]]]

Comment: You can easily achieve this with two minor modifications to the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59397143/scala-task-return-mapping) Also, why do you insist in looking for solutions without using **cats**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Task.sequence](https://monix.io/docs/2x/eval/task.html#gather-results-from-a-seq-of-tasks), and then map `flatten` over the resulting list of lists, e.g:

```
val res: List[Task[List[Header]]] = ...
Task.sequence(res).map(_.flatten)
```

If you need parallel execution over the results, you can take a look on `Task.gather`.

Comment: How it works can you explain in detail, it is possible to do using case class or foldleft

Comment: Task.sequence, takes a Seq[Task[A]] and returns a Task[Seq[A]], thus transforming any sequence of tasks into a task with a sequence of results and with ordered effects and results. This means that the tasks WILL NOT execute in parallel.

Also you can probably: `Task.sequence(res).flatten`

Answer (score 4):

That use case is covered by the function `flatSequence`: https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/v2.1.0/core/src/main/scala/cats/Traverse.scala#L86

As you can see it takes an `F[G[F[A]]` and turns it into a `G[F[A]]`. Now replace `F` with `List` and `G` with `Task` and you've got what you need. This will work for any `F` with a `Traverse` and `FlatMap` instance and any `G` with an `Applicative` instance.

If you want to run the tasks in parallel instead, you can use `parFlatSequence` found here: https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/v2.1.0/core/src/main/scala/cats/Parallel.scala#L155